# Robot Framework - TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I’m implementing robot framework automation using selenium library for one of our web application testing. there are two different URLs which targets different markets. i completed the automation for one of the web application. The other Web app has same format and element so I was able to reuse the code from first one.

However, while executing below code which waits for process to complete and then ends the test case, i’m getting an error which does not happen with the another web app testing which has similar code.

```
`Wait Until Element Contains    web element    text    timeout=1000s`
```

this process takes no more than 5 mins but i kept timeout at 1000s as it may take longer sometimes.
during this step test case fails and below error is displayed

[errorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5ONl.png)

can someone please help? thanks in advance.

I've tried increasing the timeout, but i'm facing same error